# How do I toggle a child element when clicking "this" from outside of the parent in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you take a look at my code.. clicking on the parent hides the child. What I want it to do is, to be able to create an a `href` outside of the parent, and have that as the one to trigger the hide function of the child. I can easily pull this off by assigning ID's but I would like to know how I would be able to pull this off using `$(this)` so that I can be re-usable?

`onClick $(this)` link - target `$(this)` parent div - hide `$(this)` child div

```
<div class="trigger-collapse">   
     <h1>Anything here?</h1>
     <div class="content-collapse">
        <h4>Hello</h4>
        <p>We’re working really hard to not act like other wireless carriers. 
           At T‐Mobile you will always get fair and simple pricing, anytime upgrades, 
           a fast nationwide 4G network, no annual contracts, no overages and no 
           restrictions. Ever.
        </p>
     </div><!-- content collapse -->
</div> <!-- trigger collapse -->
```

The jQuery Script so far

```
$('.trigger-collapse').click(function() {
    $(this).children('div.content-collapse').toggle()
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question seemed little confusing but this might be the solution you want. I've put an anchor tag outside the content-collapse div but pointed to that div getting the parent node/element.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="trigger-collapse">   
    <h1>Anything here?</h1>
    <div class="content-collapse">
        <h4>Hello</h4>
        <p>We’re working really hard to not act like other wireless carriers. 
       At T‐Mobile you will always get fair and simple pricing, anytime upgrades, 
       a fast nationwide 4G network, no annual contracts, no overages and no 
       restrictions. Ever.
        </p>
   </div><!-- content collapse -->
   <a id ="outsideLink" href="#">Outside</a>
</div>
```

**jQuery :**

```
$("#outsideLink").click(function(){
    //first got the anchor tag refence, then it's parent element and finally the desired div element
    $(this).parent().find("div.content-collapse").toggle();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/VYE79/)

Comment: That worked out perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. I changed the outside link to a class. and copy and pasted the entire thing a few time to see if it works, and it worked out perfect. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 0):

that sounds like it would get confusing really quickly.

I would give them classes (making it reusable) wrap it in a class div, once you find that you can easily find the trigger and target. for extra points put your code in a function. Then you can use custom classes.

If that won't work you could use events.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this sort of depends on how you want it laid out.

If the `<a href>` tag precedes your `trigger-collapse` div, then you could do something like this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.trigger-collapse').find('.content-collapse').toggle()
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dY9cG/)

Or, if it is after, you can swap `.next()` out for `.prev()`

There are other selectors such as `.siblings()` which can also be used.

Setting IDs on the elements is certainly the easiest way, or classes if you want to have multiple correlations. This shouldn't really make it less re-usable. But whichever way you want to approach it, there's more than one correct answer, really.

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<div class="trigger-collapse">   
 <h1>Anything here?</h1>
 <div class="content-collapse" style="background-color:red; overflow:hidden;">

    <h4>Hello</h4>
    <p>We’re working really hard to not act like other wireless carriers. 
       At T‐Mobile you will always get fair and simple pricing, anytime upgrades, 
       a fast nationwide 4G network, no annual contracts, no overages and no 
       restrictions. Ever.
    </p>

 </div><!-- content collapse -->
```

jQuery:

```
$(".trigger-collapse").toggle(function(){
      $(".content-collapse").animate({height:0},600);
},function(){
      $(".content-collapse").animate({height:114},600);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DRACg/2/